# How to say "still waiting for me"?

Tags: grammar

So I am trying to translate the sentence "Are you still waiting for me?" and I have translated it to "僕にとってまだ待っているのか?". Would this be a natural sentence or is it possible to make the sentence shorter?

Comment: シマッタ, I mean 「僕にとってまだ待っているのか」

Comment: Hi! Welcome to JLSE. Please avoid giving your question vague titles. The title should give users an idea of what the question is about before they click it.

Comment: "僕にとってまだ待っているのか" is ungrammatical.  Note that English "for" cannot always translate into Japanese にとって.  "[this is] one giant leap for mankind" *can* translate into 人類**にとって**は偉大な飛躍[である].

Answer (score 2):

待つ is a transitive verb, meaning that you can use it with an object. を marks objects of action, so it would be correct to say 僕を待つ to mean "wait for me". There are probably a trillion ways to say what you want, but this I think would be the straightforward choice:

> まだ僕を待っているのか

You can of course just shorten it to "[are you] still waiting?"
まだ待っているのか

Comment: Okay, but did I use にとって in the wrong way?

Comment: @user13842 Yes, because にとって is a way to say "regarding X" or "concerning X". Imagine saying "Concerning me, are you still waiting?". It sounds just as weird in Japanese :) And regardless(no pun intended), if you're using a transitive verb you need to properly mark your object.

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry for the late answer. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Also, is there any clear difference between について ついて and にっといて?

Comment: They are clearly different. See this relevant answer: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29113/difference-between-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-and-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6